# exit().remove() doesn't remove obsolete elements

Tags: d3.js, data-binding

http://jsfiddle.net/brunoperel/z6qfttmr/

I'm trying to create elements on-the-fly, depending on the link which has been clicked on :

```
d3.select('#processes').selectAll('.processLaunch').data(helperProcessesData).enter()
    .append('a')
        .classed('processLaunch', true)
        .attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)')
        .text(function(d) { return d.text; })
        .on('click', function(d) {
            var currentProcess=d.name;
            var filteredData = helperStepsData.filter(function(d) { return d.process === currentProcess; });

            var helperStepsForProcess = d3.select('div#helperContainer').selectAll('.helperStep')
                .data(filteredData);
            console.log('Filtered data : '+JSON.stringify(filteredData));
            console.log('Linked data : '+JSON.stringify(helperStepsForProcess.data()));
            helperStepsForProcess.enter()
                .append('div').text(function(d) { return 'Step '+d.step+' : '+d.title; });
            helperStepsForProcess.exit().remove();
    });
```

There are (at least !) two things that I don't understand here :

- Each time I click on a link, related texts are added to the page, but obsolete ones are not removed even though I called `.exit().remove()` on the selection. Why ?
- When I do a `console.log` of the data that is about to be bound to the selection's elements, it returns an array of objects, which is fine. But when, in the line after this, I retrieve the data which has been bound to the elements, I get an array of `undefined` objects. Why don't I get an array of objects as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just forgot to add the respective class on the steps:

```
helperStepsForProcess.enter()
            .append('div')
            .attr('class', 'helperStep');

helperStepsForProcess.text(function(d) { 
   return 'Step '+d.step+' : '+d.title; });
```

Adding this in your fiddle return the expected result.

I hope this helps!

Update: https://jsfiddle.net/chroth/z6qfttmr/2/

Comment: You're right, it's better : I don't get extra lines if I fix this.
However, [I don't see the correct text](http://jsfiddle.net/z6qfttmr/1/): If you click on "Launch process 2", I don't see the expected text "First step of the second process", but instead I see "First step", which means that the first element wasn't updated with the new text, although the second element was removed like expected. Why ?

Comment: Updated the fiddle, forgot to put the text in some 'update' event instead on enter(). Ok like this?

Comment: Thank you ! I hadn't realized that the updated elements had to be processed as well with text()